# cannot save data through Ajax laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, laravel-8, ajaxform

when normal request performed , it saves data without any error but through ajax it returned error: [object HTMLDivElement].

but when I comment the create function in controller , request is performed successfully.

- csrf token added in meta tag
- data can be saved through normal request but not with the ajax
- Route is properly configured

ass far as i understand , error is generating while performing create function in the controller.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    Contact::create($data);
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Message Sent Successfully']);       

}
```

**Blade.php**

```
<!-- ======= Contact Section ======= -->
<section id="contact" class="contact">
  <form method="POST" action="{{route('contact.store')}}" class="php-email-form" id="contact-form">
          <div class="row gy-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            </div>
            @csrf
            <div class="col-md-6 ">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <div class="loading">Loading</div>
              <div class="error-message"></div>
              <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>

              <button type="submit" id="send-message">Send Message</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </form>
</section><!-- End Contact Section -->
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
});
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $('.loading').addClass("d-block");

    var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var subject = $("input[name=subject]").val();
    var message = $("input[name=message]").val();


    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:"{{route('contact.store')}}",
       data:{name:name, email:email, subject:subject, message:message},
       success:function(data){
         $('.sent-message').addClass("d-block");
          $('.sent-message').text(data.success); 
          //$('#contact-form').trigger("reset");
       },
       complete: function(){
        $('.loading').removeClass("d-block");
      },
       error:function(data){
        $('.error-message').addClass("d-block");
        $('.error-message').text(data.error);
       }
    });

});
});
```

Comment: console.log(data.error) may get you more details in the devtool

Comment: try to print your request data first `dd($request->all());` in store function and check the response in network tab of console.